# Problemas con libreria Carousel, ActionButton

Tags: react-native, carrusel

Estoy realizando un proyecto en React native y estoy usando Carousel y ActionButton y los tengo instalados pero me presentan el siguiente mensaje  adjunto imágenes [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecuto los siguiente comando y me para actualizar Carousel y el Action Button

el del actionButton es:

yarn add react-native-action-button

y el del Carousel

yarn add react-native-banner-carousel

pero el mensaje persiste, la pregunta es como se que versión es la que debo ejecutar para evitar estos mensajes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al revisar la librería `react-native-banner-carousel` veo que su última actualización fue hace 2 años. Desde la versión 16.6+ (si mal no recuerdo) de React se empezó a sustituir métodos de los ciclos de vida, anteponiendo un `UNSAFE_` antes del método. Es decir, para tu ejemplo específico, la librería que usas en algún lugar de su código sobreescribe un método llamado `componentWillReceiveProps` y para la nueva versión de React debería llamarse `UNSAFE_ componentWillReceiveProps`.

Lo que yo te recomendaría puede ser bien:

- Enviar un PR al proyecto renombrando el método, ya que funciona de la misma forma, solo que no se llama igual.
- Silenciar el warning con `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['componentWillReceiveProps']);` ya que aún tiene soporte, y arroja un warning, no un error, pero en algún punto, con una futura actualización si será un error.
- Pasarte a una versión más abajo de React-Native v0.60 donde se integre con otra versión de React que no tenga este inconveniente. Pero es posible tener otros inconvenientes con paquetes que si estén 100% actualizados.
- Simplemente ignorarlo

Cualquier duda, pregunta o inquietud, no olvides en comentar

Comment: tengo una pregunta que pasa si al remplazar el componentWillReceiveProps  por el   UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps me debería seguir funcionando igual ? y con relacion a la de actionButton también presenta el mismo problema ?

Comment: uno como sabe en que parte esta el componente es que no lo encuentro parap oder reemplazarlo

Comment: No te recomiendo modificar ningún archivo dentro de la carpeta `node_modules` lo ideal sería ir directamente al repositorio en GitHub hacer un fork, corregir y luego hacer un Pull Request con la corrección. Con respecto a tu otra pregunta, si, sigue funcionando igual solamente se cambió el nombre

Comment: la verdad el otro día hice algo así el otro día ya modifique el archivo. y pues si l oque quiero es ponerle el nombre pero no lo encuentro la verdad

Comment: De poder puedes, pero piensa que `node_modules` es una carpeta de la que no se guarda nada en un repositorio, entonces cuando intentes usar tu proyecto desde otro equipo, no podrás. Y muchas más cosas por la que no te recomiendo modificar directamente el archivo. Como cuando la librería cambie de versión

Comment: si muchas gracias